# CSS grid with each column different height

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I have a grid of accordion with two column I am having issue when any of the accordion is opened it takes the height of its next column.

See the default state of the all accordions (all are closed).[image]

Here in second image when opened any of them lets say Item 2 (notice the height of the left column Item 1 it should not have height of Item 2 but height of closed item)
[image]

My requirement is when I open any accordion it should have its height rest all items remains as its so only opened item should be expanded.

I am using tailwind CSS below is the code I am using.

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-x-8 gap-y-3 lg:grid-cols-2">
    <div class="border-b border-secondary">Item 1</div>
    <div class="border-b border-secondary">Item 2</div>
    <div class="border-b border-secondary">Item 3</div>
    <div class="border-b border-secondary">Item 4</div>
    ....
</div>
```

Comment: I believe that the layout you want is called "masonry" and it seems like there is no universal solution for this (if using pure CSS). If you want a universal solution, JS will be needed